# How to handle child window in Xephyr

Tags: graphics, xorg

I need to use `Xephyr` to run an old application that requires 8-bit color depth.
This following command works but with a problem.

```
xephyr -ac -screen 800x600x8 -reset :2 &
```

This application I am testing has certain functions that generate new popup windows, for example showing graphs after choosing a part of the image. When the new popup window opens, it overlaps on the top left of the previous window and hides some of the images on it, but I need to see both the images and the graph on the same screen.

I have tried to start a window manager inside of the `Xephyr`, some of them do work such as Awesome WM but not with 8-bit color depth.
`Xephyr` is such a great tool, I wonder if there's a way to solve this problem without a WM.

Comment: `xdotool windowmove`?

Comment: I tried it out and xdotool does work! I didn't know this tool, it's quite cool! I'll use this until I can find a even better solution, such as a WM working with 8bit. Thank you very much!